# Find with complete proofs the exterior points of the set $S = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R ^2\ :\ |x+y|<1\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Find with complete proofs the exterior points of the following set:
$$S = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}\ :\ |x+y|<1\}$$

I see that the exterior points of the set are $|x+y|>1$ , but how can I prove this? 
Could anyone help me please?

thanks!

Comment: Here is a question about interior points of the same set: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2508600/find-with-complete-proofs-the-interior-points-of-the-following-set

Comment: Did you mean to say $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ rather than $(x,y)\in\mathbb R$? (The same goes for your other question.)

Comment: I am sorry, I have corrected it @MartinSleziak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T=\{(x,y)\in{\bf{R}^{2}}: |x+y|>1\}$. As you have posted another similar question to this, you should know how to prove that $(S^{c})^{\circ}$ (the exterior) contains $T$. Now it suffices to show that any $(u,v)$ with $|u+v|=1$ is a boundary point of $S^{c}$, for then any $(x,y)\in(S^{c})^{\circ}$ cannot be $|x+y|=1$ (of course $(x,y)$ cannot be in $S$ because $(S^{c})^{\circ}\subseteq S^{c}$), as $(x,y)\in\overline{S^{c}}$, the only choice is that $(x,y)\in T$.

The claim that $(u,v)$ with $|u+v|=1$ is a boundary point of $S^{c}$: A moment of thought should lead to the fact that $(u,v)$ is a boundary of $S^{c}$ if and only if $(u,v)$ is also a boundary of $S$. Consider the map $f:(x,y)\rightarrow|x+y|$, $f^{-1}[-1,1]=f^{-1}\overline{(-1,1)}\subseteq\overline{f^{-1}(-1,1)}=\overline{S}$ by the continuity of $f$. But $f^{-1}[-1,1]$ is closed and containing $S$, so $\overline{S}\subseteq f^{-1}[-1,1]$, so $\overline{S}=f^{-1}[-1,1]=\{|x+y|\leq 1\}$. Now $\{|x+y|=1\}=\{|x+y|\leq 1\}-S=\overline{S}-S=\text{boundary of }S$.